# Visual Studio report wizard similar to Report Builder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

Using Visual Studio 2012 to design SSRS reports, I am able to add a new chart or a new table perfectly fine. They are unformatted, however. How can I launch the nice table/tablix/chart wizard inside Visual Studio like we are able to do in Report Builder 3?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Report Builder wizard isn't available in Visual Studio. The closest available is the Report Wizard:

[image]

Comment: So the only way is to run the wizard into a different report and copy/paste it over? Has anybody found a better way?

Comment: @Terry Didn't realize you were talking about adding a chart/table to an existing report -- but the Report Builder wizard isn't available in Visual Studio, no matter if the report is new or existing.